I deleted old version JavaFX and downloaded a new version and in command line it shows no source files
Currently, I updated my java SDK from version 18 to version 21.0.3 in my Mac (Monterey 12.7.4). Before installation i deleted the previous version sdk completely as below:
sudo rm -fr /Library/Internet\ Plug-Ins/JavaAppletPlugin.plugin
sudo rm -fr /Library/PreferencePanes/JavaControlPanel.prefPane
sudo rm -fr ~/Library/Application\ Support/Oracle/Java
The new installed java sdk 21.0.3 work properly, it can compile and run java programs. The problem is the JavaFx. I deleted the previous JavaFx version 17 (by deleting the JavaFx folder) and downlaod a new version 21.0.3 and unzipped in the same postion. Since then, the JavaFX can't work. When I typed in the terminal:
javac  --module-path=/Users/xing/javafx-sdk-javafx-sdk-21.0.3/lib
error: no source files
This is what exactly what i did before with the previous version JavaFx. But now it shows "no source files". I searched from web tried all the way, but things just keep unchanged. I set up Eclipse but the problem is the same. It took me serveral days to search and try all the methods. Is there anyperson can help? Thank you very much.
I tried different versions of javafx but it remain the same.

The syntax is javac <options> <source files>, where <source files> are the sources to be compiled by the tool (and can be omitted if compiling module(s) via --module). You did not pass any source files, so the tool fails. The error is not related to JavaFX.

Dear Slaw, thank you for your help very much! I checked that
When I was setting the Default VM Arguments in Eclipse, I mistakenly set it to:
-p /Users/xing/javafx-sdk-21.0.3/lib -add-modules=ALL-MODULE-PATH
(there shall two ‘-’ in front of ‘add’).
After correcting this, Eclipse works properly with JavaFX files.

If you have solved this, you can answer your own question as long as you can achieve 15 reputation.

You can't compile a source file without providing a source file.
As noted in comments by Slaw:

The syntax is javac <options> <source files>, where <source files> are the sources to be compiled by the tool (and can be omitted if compiling module(s) via --module).
You did not pass any source files, so the tool fails. The error is not related to JavaFX.

Go to the JavaFX getting started page for info on how to fix this and correctly compile and execute a JavaFX application from the command line. Compile and run the hello world app following the instructions there.
The commands are:
export PATH_TO_FX=path/to/javafx-sdk-22.0.1/lib
javac --module-path $PATH_TO_FX --add-modules javafx.controls HelloFX.java
java --module-path $PATH_TO_FX --add-modules javafx.controls HelloFX

I don't recommend this approach (compiling and running at the command line by directly using javac and java commands) as a method of development for anything beyond trivial applications.  Instead, I recommend using a build tool (e.g. Maven) integrated with an IDE.  Instructions on doing that are also in the openjfx document I linked, or the idea documentation.

I tried in the command line, and it compiled, but failed to run as it shown below:
javac --module-path=/Users/xing/javafx-sdk-21.0.3/lib --add-modules=ALL-MODULE-PATH Login.java
java --module-path=/Users/xing/javafx-sdk-21.0.3/lib --add-modules=ALL-MODULE-PATH Login
Error: Could not find or load main class Login
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Login (wrong name: login/Login)
On the other hand, if I replace Login.java with a non-JavaFx file, it can compile and run with no problem.

To add additional information, please edit the question instead of posting the new info in a comment.  Comments are hard to read, unformatted, not editable, and limited in length, making them unsuitable for adding additional information to a question.

The command options you are using are different from those in my answer.  If you follow the instructions in my answer exactly to compile and run the sample hello world application, does it work in your environment?

If hello world works, but you cannot get your own application code to work, then edit the question to provide a [mcve] - complete, minimal code and exact execution commands that reproduce the error and nothing else via copy and paste with no change or addition.  Provide the code and commands in the question, plus any error messages received, with full stack traces if available,  as text, formatted as code (indent 4 spaces to treat text as code).

I am just guessing, but I think Login (wrong name: login/Login) means that the Login class is in a module named login so you need to qualify the class name with the module name to fully specify it.  Hard to say without the actual code to reproduce this, including the originally requested module-info.java if there is one.  Additionally, I think if you have a module defined, you must place code in a package, it can't be in the root package.  If a module is defined, the module needs to export the package with the application class in it, as specified in the Application javadoc.

There is no module defined. The naming process I followed from the Oracle:  https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/get-started-tutorial/get_start_apps.htm     (the HelloWorld and Login sample code). I tried with the new HelloFX code, but the problem remains the same.

The Java 8 tutorial is not written for modern JavaFX versions.  Follow the tutorial from openjfx that I linked.  Instead of editing my answer to add extra information, please edit the question and put the extra information there.

The HelloFX code from openjfx.io is different from the code in your edit.  The openjfx.io has no package statement in the source code.  But the code in your edit request has a line package helloFX; . That is the cause of your error.  You should remove it.  Otherwise, if you use a package, the code organizaton and execution command should be different.

Hi Jewelsea, thank you for your time and help.  I just tried out an answer: First cd to the src directory rather than the package fold, and input the java command there but put the package name in front of the java file as it shows below:
src % java --module-path $PATH_TO_FX --add-modules javafx.controls helloFX.HelloFX
then the code runs.

Taking the suggestions of Jewelsea, I just tried out what the problem is:
First cd to the src directory rather than the package fold, and input the java command there but put the package name in front of the java file as it shows below:
src % java --module-path $PATH_TO_FX --add-modules javafx.controls helloFX.HelloFX
then the code runs.

Taking the suggestions of Jewelsea, I just tried out what the problem is
First cd to the src directory rather than the package fold, and input the java command there but put the package name in front of the java train as it shows below
src java-- module- path$PATH_TO_FX-- add- modulesjavafx.controlshelloFX.HelloFX
also the law runs.

There are two identical answers from different accounts.  Please delete this answer with this account and leave the answer created by the original asker account "David007".
